# How to display data in dataTable when resulted data has relation and fetched using eloquent model a

Tags: laravel-5, datatables, eloquent

I am trying to display data using dataTables. In my controller i fetch data from three tables using model eloquent with relations. I am confused how can i display that data which is fetched with relations.

My controller code.

```
public function create(){
    $shippings=ShippingPreference::with('shippingChannel','shippingMethod')->get();
    return Datatables::of($shippings)->make(true);
}
```

and my blade file

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
      $('#simpletable').DataTable({
        //dataType  :'text/html',
        processing  :true,
        serverSide  :true,
        ajax    :"{{route('shippingPreference.create')}}",
        columns   :[
         // { data: 'id', name: 'id'},
          { data: 'channel_name', name: 'channel_name'},
          { data: 'process_type', name: 'process_type'},
          { data: 'market_place_shipping_method_name', name: 'market_place_shipping_method_name'},
          { data: 'channel_method', name: 'channel_method'},
        ]

      });

    });

</script>
```

In above blade file 'channel_name' and 'channel_method' are fetched with relations. How can i display these two fields on dataTable.